# How to implement a retry SOAP request flow if the first try fails

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I'm working with Websphere Message Broker V8.0, I have the next flow for a simple SOAP mediation:

SOAP Input ->  SOAP request -> Soap Extract -> Compute Node -> SoapReply

Is there any logic that can be applied to this flow if a request fails? (timeout, system error, intermittent service)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution to your problem could be:

Connecting  both the failure terminal of your SOAP Request node to a flow that could route to the input of the SOAP Request when certain failures occur and putting a TryCatch node before and after the SOAP Request to have a separated error handling region, while connecting the fault output of the SOAP Request to a Throw node to raise exceptions when faults occur and have an error handler subflow connected to the catch terminal of the TryCatch before the SOAP Request to route to the input terminal of the SOAP Request.

As you can see, you will need to implement the error handling logic required for your application, Message Broker provides only the framework for it. So first of all you should familiarize yourself with the error handling capabilities of the message flows:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac00410_.htm